# How to find $[\mathbb Q(2^{1/5}, e^{i \pi/5}) : \mathbb Q]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to find: $\left[ \mathbb Q\left( 2^{1/5}, e^{i\pi/5} \right): \mathbb Q \right]$. I thought about:

$$\left[ \mathbb Q\left( 2^{1/5}, e^{i\pi/5} \right): \mathbb Q \right] = 5\left[ \left( \mathbb Q\left( 2^{1/5} \right) \right) \left( e^{i\pi/5} \right): \mathbb Q \left( 2^{1/5} \right) \right]$$

then trying to find the latter, but I couldn't do it. If $a = e^{i\pi/5}$, we have $a^4 - a^3 + a^2 - a + 1 =0$. I know that the polynomial $x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ but I don't know about $\mathbb Q\left(2^{1/5}\right)$.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}|\Q(e^{\pi i/5}):\Q|=4$ and
$|\Q(2^{1/5}):\Q|=5$. What does that tell you about
$|\Q(2^{1/5},e^{\pi i/5}):\Q|$?

Comment: Oh, so $4$ and $5$ (thus $20 = \text{lcm}(4,5)$) is a divisor of it, and at the same time it is at most $20$ since the degree of $e^{i\pi/5}$ is at most $4$ over $\mathbb Q(2^{1/5})$, so it is exactly $20$.